# How to programmatically take screenshot of selected range in Excel for Mac?

Tags: macos, automation, office-automation

I'm developing an electron app which has the feature that users can import an Excel file (.xlsx) and the app shows screenshots of user-selected ranges.
This app needs to run on Windows and Mac. 
I think it's possible on Windows but haven't found a possible way on Mac.

## On Windows

I'm planning to realize that with `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`.
I'm going to make a simple C# helper program and execute it from electron.

The helper program works like:

1. It opens Excel and the .xlsx file. (using `Excel.Application.Workbooks.Open`)
2. (The user selects some cell ranges and try to close Excel.)
3. It handles `Application_WorkbookBeforeClose` event and takes screenshots with `Range.CopyPicture`.

I hope there won't be a big problem.

## On Mac

This is the problem.
I was planning to do the same as above with .NET Core.
However, I found it doesn't support COM interoperability.
I've also looked into **JavaScript API for Office**, but it seems it doesn't have `Range.CopyPicture` method.
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/javascript/api/excel/excel.range?view=office-js#method-details

Are there any alternative ways to realize this feature?
The user operation doesn't have to be the same on Windows and on Mac.
Other languages such as Java, AppleScript, VBA can be used.

**On Mac (with Visual Studio for Mac), I've tried:**

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace VSConsoleProgramTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Excel.Application excelApp;
            excelApp = new Excel.Application();
        }
    }
}
```

and faild in 
`Unhandled Exception: System.PlatformNotSupportedException: COM is not supported`

Comment: The COM technology exists only on Windows. So, the code you tried to execute on Mac doesn't make any sense there.

Comment: @Eugene  Thanks. Then I'm asking how to do `Range.CopyPicture`-like thing on Mac.